# how to print the error message shown in a webpage - selenium python

Tags: python, selenium

I have a text box which will display error message if enterd text is not correct

```
<label class="error" for="first_name" style="display: block;">Invalid first name</label>
```

The property `style="display:block;"` will be `style="display:none;"` if error is not shown

I have tried `error = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('.error').text` but it returns blank text.

Please help me find a solution

Also :

The HTML of the text field is shown below

```
<div class="regTextbox_small">

<input id="first_name" class="regBox_cl_small" type="text" value="" placeholder="First Name" onblur="this.placeholder = 'First Name'" onfocus="this.placeholder = ''" name="first_name">
</input>
```

The part of html with error message is shown only when error occurs

Comment: Are there any other labels with class "error"? you need to check for other labels too. There can be a case where webdriver is finding a label with class 'error' and which does not have any text inside it. The way webdriver works is that if there are more than one element found from findElement method, webdriver will consider the first element, which in your case COULD be another label with class 'error'

Comment: I would try `error = driver.find_element_xpath('//label[@class="error"]').text` instead (inside a `try/except` block of course, in case the element is not there).

Comment: Now i found the solution.

Now i have a doubt. What if there is multiple error message under this class ? can i print every error message? how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for that you can use jquery..

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $("input:text").keyup(function () {
    if (isNaN(obj.value))
{
document.getElementById("errorlabel").style.dispaly="block";
}

});
</script>

<input type="text"/><label id="errorlabel" class="error" for="first_name" style="display: block;">Invalid first name</label>
```

I just try to show that you can do that like this. suppose if in textbox if tried to enter string then it give me error and the label with an error message will be display.

hopefully it will help you.

Comment: The OP does not want to show an error label. OP wants to find an existing label in the DOM which is an error label using selenium webdriver api.

Comment: Now i found the solution. Now i have a doubt. What if there is multiple error message under this class ? can i print every error message? how?

Comment: if suppose there is a class which contain all the error messages then you can use for loop to print the error messages.

Answer (score -1):

You can try parsing the html page using libraries like BeautifulSoup or

"driver.page_source" will give you the html data. Assign it to a variable and use regex to retrieve whatever you want.

Comment: There is no need to go for parsing libraries here. Selenium WebDriver API is good enough to get hold of elements in the DOM.